# In AzureDevops CI pipeline how to check if missing to add-migration in EF Core 3

Tags: azure-devops

I have a CI pipeline, in Azure DevOps, to build a .net core 3 project which uses EF Core 3, I need a way to check if the developer missed to do `Add-Migration` after they changed the model in the system.

I thought about, somehow, do `Add-Migration temp` and check the generated file if it doesn't have any `Up` or `Down` steps in it, don't know how yet.

Is there a better way to do it?